# Can an edit to a deleted answer automatically raise a flag?

Tags: feature-request, edits, flags, deleted-answers, automatic-flags

I just [ran into a situation](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1216/answer-deleted-by-moderator-but-would-have-preferred-edit) that seems like it could be handled better:

1. Answer is deleted by moderator
2. User edits answer to resolve problems
3. Nobody knows about this

In my case, the user then opened a thread in meta which brought it to my (the moderator's) attention.  The user could have flagged the answer instead of posting in meta (but they didn't know this).

It seems to me that edits to deleted questions and answers should automatically trigger a moderator review so that corrections don't go unnoticed.

Comment: Or at least a pop-up message mentioning that they should flagged the post when they're ready for it to be considered again.

Comment: I up voted this, but with the type of stuff I delete as a mod, I am not sure if any really could be edited back into shape.

Comment: Except for self-deleted answers. If I edit a self-deleted answer, I am either letting other users who can see it know what is going on, or I am getting ready to undelete it myself.